# BigQuery: How to get an accurate count of events for Google Analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract data from BigQuery in one large table for creating a model. Using Google's public dataset, I was able to figure out some of the query. What's confusing me is the query below shows Total_Events greater than 0 even if there is no Event Category, Action, or Label for that row. Please note, I'm not looking to get event volume for a specific category or label. I'm looking to get an export of all events.

```
  SELECT
  date,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  visitStartTime,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  trafficSource.adContent,
  trafficSource.medium,
  trafficSource.source,
  device.deviceCategory,
  page.pagePath,
  page.pageTitle,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS Pageviews,
  page.pagePathLevel1,
  page.pagePathLevel2,
  page.pagePathLevel3,
  page.pagePathLevel4,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS Event_Category,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS Event_Action,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS Event_Label,
  COUNT(*) AS Total_Events,

FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits

WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20160801'
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND totals.visits = 1

GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

ORDER BY
  Total_Events DESC
```

1. How is that possible?
2. What should the query look like so that the Total_Events column shows 0 if there is no Event Category, Action, and Label and shows a positive number for any row that does have an Event Category, Action, and Label?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you will want to do is filter `hits.type = 'EVENT'`.  Hits of type `PAGE` will/should not have EC/EL/EA.  This will eliminate most of your problem, there are still a few `EVENT` hits that are missing event info.  This could be an issue with the sample data set or a tracking issue if this is based on real data.

Replace `COUNT(*) AS Total_Events` in line 22 with `COUNT(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory) AS Total_Events`. This change tells BigQuery to count only `eventCategory` hits as opposed to all hits.

```
SELECT
  date,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  visitStartTime,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  trafficSource.adContent,
  trafficSource.medium,
  trafficSource.source,
  device.deviceCategory,
  page.pagePath,
  page.pageTitle,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS Pageviews,
  page.pagePathLevel1,
  page.pagePathLevel2,
  page.pagePathLevel3,
  page.pagePathLevel4,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS Event_Category,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS Event_Action,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS Event_Label,
  COUNT(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory) AS Total_Events,
```